# How to parse Android in-app deep links to communicate with backend

Tags: android, kotlin, chatbot, deep-linking

I'm writing an Android chatbot where the backend will give you options in the form of buttons, and by clicking on those buttons communicate with the backend by sending back the options you picked. The deep links will be retrieved from the backend. What is best Android solution for parsing deeplinks of this form?

app://app.com/dialog/submitintent?value=No%2C%20I%27d%20like%20to%20select%20character%28s%29%20to%20review&metadata=2

Comment: Have you tried android.net.Uri? `Uri.parse` to parse it. And then, you can check its content via `getPathSegments` and other methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the link you open/view, you'll get the link either in onCreate() or onNewIntent() methods:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handleDirectDeepLink(getIntent());
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleDirectDeepLink(intent);
}

private void handleDirectDeepLink(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null || !intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) || intent.getData() == null) return;
    if ((getIntent().getFlags() & FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) return;

    List<String> pathSegments = intent.getData().getPathSegments();
    // you will get your link segments here in pathSegments
}
```